# How to Execute stored procedure from SQL Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in oracle and want to test it from SQLPlus.

If I use

```
execute  my_stored_proc (-1,2,0.01)
```

I get this error

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to my_stored_proc
```

The beginning for the proc is this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE my_stored_proc
( a IN NUMBER, 
  b IN NUMBER, 
  c IN NUMBER, 
  z out NUMBER
) AS ....
```

Do I need to provide the a var for the out parameter, is so how?  I tried:

```
var z  NUMBER;
```

But get this error when I try to run the proc

```
execute  my_stored_proc (-1,2,0.01,z) 
PLS-00201: identifier 'Z' must be declared
```

Also when I  was in SQL-Developer it gave me the usage and it show the inputs in reverse order, that is:

```
execute my_stored_proc(z number,c number,b number,a number);
```

Do you provide them in reverse order or is that just something with SQL-Developer

I did not write the procedure and I don't normally deal with them so I could be missing something obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

You have two options, a PL/SQL block or SQL*Plus bind variables:

```
var z number

execute  my_stored_proc (-1,2,0.01,:z)

print z
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put z as an bind variable.

The following EXECUTE command runs a PL/SQL statement that references a stored procedure:

```
SQL> EXECUTE -
> :Z := EMP_SALE.HIRE('JACK','MANAGER','JONES',2990,'SALES')
```

Note that the value returned by the stored procedure is being return into :Z

Comment: -1 a function can be used in an expression, a procedure cannot.