# How to call a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO(
                                                    P_ID               IN     NUMBER,
                                                    P_AGE                 OUT NUMBER,
                                                    P_OCCUPATION          OUT VARCHAR2,
                                                    P_LASTSTATEMENT       OUT VARCHAR2
                                                   ) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT AGE,
           OCCUPATION,
           LASTSTATEMENT
      INTO P_AGE,
           P_OCCUPATION,
           P_LASTSTATEMENT
      FROM crossallcustomers
     WHERE crossallcustomers.id = P_ID;
END;
```

**EDIT:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> VARIABLE P_ID NUMBER;
SQL> EXEC GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO(123,:P_ID);
```

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number
>   or types of arguments in call to 'GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO' ORA-06550:
>   line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

Comment: What's the issue? What have you tried?

Comment: *PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to* when i m calling the procedure

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong with your code without seeing it. Please post your code.

Comment: *CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO(
  P_ID  IN NUMBER,
  P_AGE OUT NUMBER,
  P_OCCUPATION  OUT VARCHAR2,
  P_LASTSTATEMENT OUT VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT AGE,
    OCCUPATION,
    LASTSTATEMENT
      INTO P_AGE,
           P_OCCUPATION,
           P_LASTSTATEMENT
      FROM crossallcustomers
     WHERE crossallcustomers.id = P_ID;
END;*

Comment: If you have an issue in the procedure call, we need to see the code you use to call the procedure, not only the procedure itself.

Comment: *i have n't any code this procedure .i m testing in sql plus cmd. try to execute this procedure  pls-00306 error was raised*

Comment: How did you tried to run? What did you write in sqlPlus to run this procedure? The error says that you are calling the procedure the wrong way, so please post what you wrote to call the procedure and gave you error

Comment: *   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> VARIABLE P_ID NUMBER;
SQL> EXEC GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO(123,:P_ID);
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

Comment: @PAVANVARMA What about the other 2 OUT parameters? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115423/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-from-sql-plus

Comment: i have taken 2 out parameter in arguments list for single result stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a procedure that has four parameters, with no default value, by only passing two parameters.

This is an example of how to call your procedure:

```
declare
    V_AGE              NUMBER;    
    V_OCCUPATION       VARCHAR2(10);
    V_LASTSTATEMENT    VARCHAR2(10);
begin
    GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO (
                                P_ID               => 1              ,
                                P_AGE              => V_AGE          ,
                                P_OCCUPATION       => V_OCCUPATION   ,
                                P_LASTSTATEMENT    => V_LASTSTATEMENT
                            );
end;
```

or, with variables:

```
SQL> variable V_AGE           number;
SQL> variable V_OCCUPATION    varchar2(10);
SQL> variable V_LASTSTATEMENT varchar2(10);
SQL> exec GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO (P_ID => 1, P_AGE => :V_AGE, P_OCCUPATION => :V_OCCUPATION , P_LASTSTATEMENT => :V_LASTSTATEMENT );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: If the answer is right for you, please accept it. It's a way to both mark the question as closed and to say thanks. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more

Comment: Aleksej sir.could u please tell me books or site name for oracle 11g for more practise and good knowledge

Comment: [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/index.htm) is often underrated, but IMHO is a great place to start. Even for [11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/index.htm)

Comment: @Aleksej - Oracle documentation is rarely underrated by people who know about it :). In fact the Oracle DB docs are amongst the best examples of product documentation there are. Alas, people don't know where to find them, or else how to use them.

Comment: @APC and in fact, just as I say "look Oracle docs", the following comment is ( if I understand well) a request for something different

Comment: @PAVANVARMA - there is a link to the Oracle docs at the start of Aleksej's comment